# Jetpack Compose: Image same width as smaller text in Column

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I would like to display an Image directly above a text in Jetpack Compose.
[image: What I want this to look like at the end]

The image is quite a bit larger than the text, but I want it to have the same width as the text, so that it looks nicer together.

```
Column {
    Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.large_app_logo),
        contentDescription = "${stringResource(id = R.string.appName)} logo",
        contentScale = ContentScale.Inside,
    )
    Text(
        text = stringResource(id = R.string.appName),
        fontSize = fontSize,
    )
}
```

The only way I have found to do this is to define a layout that measures all elements and defines then sets the width of all elements to be the same as the smallest:

```
@Composable
fun MinimalWidthColumn(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    Layout(modifier = modifier, content = content) { measurables, constraints ->
        val minWidth = measurables.minOfOrNull { it.maxIntrinsicWidth(constraints.maxHeight) } ?: constraints.maxWidth
        val actualConstraints = constraints.copy(maxWidth = minWidth)

        val placeables = measurables.map {
            it.measure(actualConstraints)
        }
        val totalHeight = placeables.sumOf { it.height }
        layout(minWidth, totalHeight) {
            // Track the y coordinate we have placed children up to
            var yPosition = 0

            // Place children in the parent layout
            placeables.forEach { placeable ->
                // Position item on the screen
                placeable.placeRelative(x = 0, y = yPosition)

                // Record the y co-ord placed up to
                yPosition += placeable.height
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then use that instead of the standard Column:

```
@Composable
fun LogoWithAppName(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, fontSize: TextUnit = 25.sp) {
    MinimalWidthColumn(
        modifier = modifier.wrapContentWidth(),
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.large_app_logo),
            contentDescription = "${stringResource(id = R.string.appName)} logo",
            contentScale = ContentScale.Inside,
        )
        Text(
            text = stringResource(id = R.string.appName),
            fontSize = fontSize,
        )
    }
}
```

It feels like a task that should be accomplishable with modifiers instead of needing to define a custom layout. Is there such a way?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Box composable to overlay the Text on top of the Image and apply a modifier to constrain the width of the Image to match the width of the Text

```
@Composable
fun ProfileLayout(
    profileImageRes: Int,
    shortName: String,
    fullName: String
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(16.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(120.dp)
                .clip(CircleShape)
        ) {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(profileImageRes),
                contentDescription = "Profile Image",
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
            )

            Text(
                text = shortName,
                color = Color.White,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6,
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)
            )
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))

        Text(
            text = fullName,
            color = Color.Gray,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1
        )
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewProfileLayout() {
    ProfileLayout(
        profileImageRes = R.drawable.header_image,
        shortName = "JD",
        fullName = "John D"
    )
}
```

Find screenshot here- https://imgur.com/NyyyPGf

Comment: I can’t test this right now but from my understanding, this would put the text on top of the image right? Does this combination of modifiers also work with a column?

Comment: Not clear what you exactly looking for. Please share your Design view image.

Comment: I added an image to show what I want the end result to look like